# I am trying to migrate the table I have created but I keep getting an error that my database is unknown.I use XAMPP 3.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Comment: Is you database actually named `laravel` or did you forget to change database name in `.env` file?

Comment: if your .env file has  DB_DATABASE=laravel, you need to create laravel schema in mysql or whatever you use.

Comment: I have actually changed the name from laravel to the name of my db but it is still not working ....and now my user id and passwords of my other projects gives me an incorrect message when i try logging in

Answer (score 0):

found this somewhere and it was helpful

The DB_USERNAME should be set to root if you do not have a default username

If no password is set on the database, clear it DB_PASSWORD

After completion of .env edit must be clear cache: php artisan config:cache

After Run the migrate Artisan command: php artisan migrate